# Maximum value of the sum of Betti numbers

Tags: algebraic-topology

In the category of all simplicial complexes that have $n+1$ vertices, it is well known that the maximum value of the sum of Betti numbers can only be achieved by some specific skeletons of the normal $n$-simplex $\Delta^n$(see [here](http://archive.ymsc.tsinghua.edu.cn/pacm_download/117/6425-11511_2006_Article_BF02392300.pdf),Theorem 1.4). The original proof is by combinitorics. I want to know how to prove this by Mayer-Vietoris sequence? Can anybody give some hints?